# Google cannot find my AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I've created an AMP compatible pages for my mobile website, but seems like Google cannot find them - Google Search Console show no AMP pages found. I deployed AMP pages almost 3 weeks ago.

What did I do:

- resubmitted AMP pages to Google
- checked AMP pages with 2 different validators - no issues

My mobile pages don't have a non-AMP version, therefore page have only one URL. I added the following to every page:

Any ideas why Google cannot find any AMP pages?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Have you visited [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/UIPBicq58ZQ;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category%243Aaccelerated-mobile-pages-amp) by the google product forum?

Comment: Yes, I did, but all suggestions mentioned there were already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

After created AMP content, you should validate your content by using Amp Test Tool to ensure that your AMP content is valid or not for Google search. If you are applicable, then use the Structured Data Testing Tool to verify your structured data.

After doing these entire if you still not able to find your Amp pages to Google then check the followings:

[image]

Otherwise, Follow the Google Search guidelines for AMP pages.

Answer (score 0):

if the AMP is validated and has the `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">` parameter it should be discoverable. Could you maybe share your site?

It can happen that Google doesn't show your page, but that doesn't mean the AMP Cache couldn't find it. Did you try to access your page on the AMP Cache?